# Open and save problems

Tags: vb.net, winforms, bitmap, gdi+

I have a function in my VB project where i scan an image and then I can change the contrast. 
I scan it and saves it *`C:\temp\my_img.tif`*.

In the `winform` the image is displayed in a `PictureBox`.

If I in the contrast function set like `img.Save("C:\temp\my_img.tif", ImageFormat.Tiff)` I get *"A generic error occurred in GDI+."*. If I however set the `filename` to something else, it works just fine.

So, how do I release the used image before saving it?

The whole function, in short:

```
Sub setContrast(ByVal C As Single)
    'filename(1) ia a "global" variable that stores the used file path, in this case "C:\temp\my_img.tif"

    Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(filename(1)) '<--- I get the image

    'A bunch of contrast stuff in some rows.....

    'Here, i should release the image...

    img.Save(filename(1), ImageFormat.Tiff) '<---Tries to save

    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, really, but `Image` implements `IDisposable`, so you should dispose it when you are done with it, or, better yet, put it in a `Using` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it using a different file name, and then, if necessary, delete the old file and rename the new file to match the old, having `Disposed` of the `Image` beforehand.

From [`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx):

> The file remains locked until the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) is disposed.

There's no wording anywhere else that says that this is somehow worked around if the same `Image` instance is trying to `Save` back to the file.